# how to transform a number in binary representation to a Snowflake number

Tags: sql, binary, user-defined-functions, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a number in binary (base-2) representation:

```
"10100110"
```

How can I transform it to a number in Snowflake?

Comment: where is this binary data coming from? Are you loading it into a table?

Comment: yup, the input for this problem comes as strings in binary form (similar problem: when the strings come in hex form)

Comment: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/binary-input-output.html

Comment: Wait, you work at Snowflake?

Comment: Yes, I work at Snowflake. Note that the linked docs refer to binary data, not to numbers in binary form "010101011110"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried with a SQL pure UDF - it worked at first, but not when using it with data over a table.

So I had to create a Javascript UDF:

```sql
create or replace function bin_str_to_number(a string)
  returns float
  language javascript
  as
  $$
    return parseInt(A, 2)
  $$
;
select bin_str_to_number('110');
```

---

For the record, this is the error I got when attempting a pure SQL UDF for the same:

`SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated`

The UDF:

```sql
create or replace function bin_str_to_number(a string)
  returns number
  as
  $$
    (select sum(value::number*pow(2,index))::number 
     from table(flatten(input=>split_string_to_char(reverse(a)))))
  $$
```

Comment: The OP is not asking for a function *per se*, so the `select` expression itself answers the question.

Comment: The SELECT expression works, until you try to apply it on data coming out from a table, unfortunately

Answer (score 2):

Snowflake does not provide number or Integer to Binary function out of the box, however these UDF  function can be used instead

I also overloaded the UDF in the event a string gets passed.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION int_to_binary(NUM VARIANT)
      RETURNS string
      LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
      AS $$
      return (NUM >>> 0).toString(2);
      $$;
 
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION int_to_binary(NUM STRING)
      RETURNS string
      LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
      AS $$
      return (NUM >>> 0).toString(2);
      $$;
```

Answer (score 0):

That was a fun challenge for this morning! If you want to do it in pure SQL:

```sql
with binary_numbers as (
    select column1 as binary_string
    from (values('10100110'), ('101101101'), ('1010011010'), ('1011110')) tab
)

select
    binary_string,
    sum(to_number(tab.value) * pow(2, (tab.index - 1))) decimal_number
from
     binary_numbers,
     table(split_to_table(trim(replace(replace(reverse(binary_numbers.binary_string), '1', '1,'), '0', '0,' ), ','), ',')) tab
group by binary_string
```

Produces:

| BINARY_STRING | DECIMAL_NUMBER |
| --- | --- |
| 10100110 | 166 |
| 101101101 | 365 |
| 1010011010 | 666 |
| 1011110 | 94 |