# Snowflake procedures Javascript or SQL

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

When writing Snowflake procedures is there any benefit of writing procedures in JavaScript or SQL or vice versa.
It depends upon the environment in the organization, if team has experience in JavaScript then they would write in JavaScript.

Is there any recommendation by Snowflake on what to use when ?

Comment: you have answered your question. It depends what the team is more experienced with. Also there is no "answer to this" so it's prone to getting closed. But to try anyways JavaScript can do more complex stuff, but executing SQL is a little more hoop jumpy, as those parts are bolted on, SQL can execute easy, but the flexible programming side is quite new (Snowflake Scripting) so presently you can bang you head on things the feel like "they should just work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you will get the best performance with a pure SQL solution, but not always:

- A UDTF in JS/Java/Python can be faster as it can use less resources (manage memory requirements): https://towardsdatascience.com/sql-puzzle-optimization-the-udtf-approach-for-a-decay-function-4b4b3cdc8596
- Sometimes some complicated SQL UDFs don't work inside a larger query, then JS/Java/Python can solve the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65299548/132438
- Java has a nice packaging mechanism to move from a software engineer's environment to Snowflake: Use a .jar.